# Cartesian coordinates array to polar coordinates in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following coordinates stored in arrays that I want to convert into polar coordinates :

```
import numpy as np

R = 1.;
NcellB = 5;
xm = np.linspace(-R, R,NcellB);
ym = np.linspace(-R, R,NcellB);
```

Is there a simple and fast way to do it?

Comment: You can find an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757297/14280520.

Comment: I saw this already, it is defined for a single couple (x, y). I was looking for a better way without having to use two for loops, which costs a bit in calculating time...

Comment: Both np.sqrt and np.arctan2 accept array as input, so no for loop is required.